# Intermittently getting 404 error, "Owner resource does not exist"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We just started noticing this yesterday as we added code to our system that automatically manages databases and collections. Previously, we created them manually through portal.azure.com. So we are running lots of tests, creating and deleting both databases and collections many times during the tests.

Intermittently, we get a 404 error with this message, "Owner resource does not exist", maybe once out of every 10 times we run our tests.

Also, in the same tests we also get the error, "The MAC signature found in the HTTP request is not the same as the computed signature". That happened twice yesterday but none today.

We are running these tests in US East.

Comment: We'd like to investigate this further. A few things few things that would help us troubleshoot: the request's activity id, timestamp, account endpoint. Can you e-mail me at andrl {at} microsoft.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this error was caused by attempting to read from a collection after it had been deleted. We thought we had shut down any such requests before deleting the database, but due to the nature of async operations, every once in a while the order of those got altered. We found that adding a 500ms delay before deleting the test database eliminated the intermittant failures.

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing this issue too during document creation via CreateDocumentAsync().

For everyone else's benefit: Make sure you're providing the correct database name. Our class structure has a variety of routing controls built in, and we were accidentally providing the DocumentDB account name rather than the logical database name when building the collection URI.

Oops.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction.  To others... when checking your database and collection names, remember they are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when my connection string was incorrect. I was testing this local and the connection string was like below:

```
AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:XXXX/;AccountKey=SOME_ALPHABETS_OF_KEY==;database=db;
```

Now remember Cosmos is **CASE SENSITIVE** , name of my db in local azure cosmos emulator was **DB** but in my connection string it is **db**. Updating this typo fixed my issue.